# How can I transform this object with strings into a normal one?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
const updatedFields = {
    "user.name": "potato",
    "plan": "diamond"
}
```

I expect it to be:

```
const obj = {
    user: {
        name: "potato"
    },
    plan: "diamond"
}
```

The code I am currently running:

```
const updatedFields = {
    "user.name": "potato",
    "plan": "diamond"
}

const obj = {}

setpath = ([p,...ps], v, o) => ps.length ? setpath(ps, v, o[p]) : o[p] = v
Object.entries(updatedFields).forEach(([p,v]) => setpath(p.split("."), v, obj))

console.log(obj)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
setpath = ([p,...ps], v, o) => ps.length ? setpath(ps, v, o[p]) : o[p] = v
                                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at setpath (/tmp/8LYm4RhWvR.js:8:72)
    at setpath (/tmp/8LYm4RhWvR.js:8:44)
    at Object.entries.forEach (/tmp/8LYm4RhWvR.js:9:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/8LYm4RhWvR.js:9:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please refer to: [Convert javascript dot notation object to nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811) and [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797). If your want to resolve your issue with the code you've posted, we can keep this question. If you are okay with any solution for creating the nested object, we can close it as a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o[p]` or the `user` is undefined initially. So, when you try to set `name` property of the `user` object, it will throw an error.

You can use the [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to set a value, if it doesn't exist. So, set `o[p] ??= {}`

```js
const updatedFields = {
    "user.name": "potato",
    "plan": "diamond"
}

const obj = {}

const setpath = ([p,...ps], v, o) => ps.length ? setpath(ps, v, o[p] ??= {}) : o[p] = v
Object.entries(updatedFields).forEach(([p,v]) => setpath(p.split("."), v, obj))

console.log(obj)
```

Also, there are alternatives this here:

- [Convert javascript dot notation object to nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811)
- [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797)

Comment: It works here on the "Run code snippet" button, but when compiling it, it is giving me the following error:

Comment: const setpath = ([p,...ps], v, o) => ps.length ? setpath(ps, v, o[p] ??= {}) : o[p] = v
                                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Comment: The error is pointing to the " ??= "

Comment: @jhnxx The syntax is not yet supported in your environment. You could replace it with `setpath(ps, v, o[p] = o[p] || {})`

Comment: Well, I think its the javascript version to be honest. Just tried another compiler and worked fine as well. So thank you!